# print array with explode function..?

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys i have a problem when i want to "print_r" my variable string that i've "explode". the detail is below..

```
$var  = "1,2,3,4,5";
$sat = explode(',',$var);

echo"`<pre>`";

print_r($sat);
```

i want to have result like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array

        (
            [new] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [new] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [new] => 3
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [new] => 4
        )
    ...
)
```

but when i'm tried my script, it was not same like above. what is wrong with my script and what should i do guys so the result of the array can be the same like above. Please help me guys!

Comment: the keys should go like "0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4"?

Comment: Maybe use `var_dump()` or `var_export()`? Don't know what is the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

Use array_map to bulid the child arrays. see [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Try closing pre tag. When you are dumping the array in your browser, you are relying on       the browser to format your array. But you are not closing the pre tag , and this doesn't help html to format the array!

```
$var = "1,2,3,4,5";

$sat = explode(',', $var);

$sat = array_map("buildArray", $sat);

dump($sat);

function buildArray($value)
{
    return array(
        'new' => $value
    );

}

function dump($res)
{
    echo '<pre>';

    print_r($res);

    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: i did but the result is like this..
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)

Comment: Ok, what output are you getting?

Comment: do you have another solution? please help..!

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)

Comment: here the output..
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)

Answer (score 1):

```
$var  = "1,2,3,4,5";
$sat = explode(',',$var);
$sat = array_map(function($value) { return array('new' => $value); }, $sat );

var_dump($sat);
```

Comment: Mr. Mark Baker

can i do it with "print_r"? is it the same..

Array(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [new] => 1
        )
...

with yours..

array(5) {

  [0]=>

  array(1) {

        ["new"]=> string(1) "1"
  }

...

Thanks! Please help..

Comment: Then just use print_r() intead of var_dump(), these are both simply methods of displaying the structure and content of the array... though you wouldn't generally use either in a production release, but typically only for debugging

Answer (score 0):

```
$var  = "1,2,3,4,5";
$sat = explode(',',$var);

function p($value) { return array('new' => $value); }

$sat = @array_map(p, $sat );

echo("<pre>");
print_r($sat);
echo("</pre>");
```

Comment: this will have exactly the same result that you want.